# ROS2 Humble: no topics published when playing BAG file

Tags: ros2

I recorded a number of topics using ros2 record.
'ros2 bag info' shows all the desired topics.
I can view the topics with rqt_bag, too.

However, when I use ros2 bag play, the topics do not get published. 'ros2 topic list' simply does not show the desired topics.

Expected behaviour: ros2 topic list showing the recorded topics of the BAG file.